# Accordion Menu Showing Issue

Tags: jquery, accordion

I created one accordion menu, it is working fine but when I click the Submenu under menu it will also slide up and then slide down like main menu. How can I resolve it. 
I have one jsfiddle file here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/AR5Zk/ Please help me.

Comment: I see a few small problems in the sample, but I'm not 100% sure what is being asked. Can you explain the improper behaviour in reproducible steps? ("1. click this 2. click that. 3. I did not want X to happen, but it does!")

Comment: 1. Navigation Sub Menu under Navigation Menu need to close when first load (Done).
2. When click on Navigation Two or Three there sub menu will work like accordion menu (Done).
3. If  click Navigation Two then it's Navigation sub menus are showing but when click on Navigation sub menus that will not slide up and slide down related Navigation structure.(Issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/FPtsz/

Comment: Thank you.. I don't want slideToggle but it is good for me now.